# Why is this learning curve changing when the training sizes don't start with 1 sample?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, sample-size, curve-fitting

I started following the tutorial to create a linear regression model with scikit from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-linear-regression-in-python-with-scikit-learn-83a8f7ae2b4f) inside jupyter notebook.
Then I decided to do a k-cross validation and plot the learning curves.
The code I wrote is this one

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
%matplotlib inline
...
# Load dataset, prepare the dataset, show dataset infos...
...
# Prepare training and testing set with 80:20 ratio
test_size = 0.2
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=42)
print("DATA SIZES from total of", X.size)
print("Training size: ", 100-test_size*100, "% of", X.size, "=", X_train.size)
print("Test size: ", test_size*100, "% of", X.size, "=", y_test.size)

# Prepare various training sizes for cross validation
train_sizes_1 = np.array([1, 19047, 38093, 57139, 76185])
train_sizes_2 = np.array([0.00001, 0.12, 0.325, 0.55, 0.775, 1.])
train_sizes_3 = np.array([0.001, 0.12, 0.325, 0.55, 0.775, 1.])

# Do k-cross validation and save learning/validation errors
regressor = LinearRegression()
val_train_sizes, val_train_scores, val_scores = learning_curve(
    regressor, X_train, y_train, train_sizes=train_sizes_1, cv = 6, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error')

val_train_scores_mean = -val_train_scores.mean(axis=1)
val_scores_mean = -val_scores.mean(axis=1)
print('Mean training scores\n\n', pd.Series(val_train_scores_mean, index=val_train_sizes))
print('\n', '-' * 20)
print('\nMean validation scores\n\n', pd.Series(val_scores_mean, index=val_train_sizes))

learning_curves_figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.title("Regression Model Learning Curve")
plt.xlabel("Training set size")
plt.ylabel("RMSE")
plt.plot(val_train_sizes, val_train_scores_mean, "o-", color="g", label='Training error')
plt.plot(val_train_sizes, val_scores_mean, "o-", color="r", label='Validation error')
plt.legend()
...
# Fit the model, predict test and show model infos...
...
```

`train_sizes_1`(with manually selected sizes) and `train_sizes_2`(with percentages) both start with 1 sample(I took the idea from [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/learning-curves-machine-learning/)) to use for the first cross-validation while `test_sizes_3`(with percentages) starts with multiple samples.
What happens with `train_sizes_1` and `train_sizes_2` is that the learning curves are pretty much like this
[image]
but with `train_sizes_3` I get this
[image]

My questions are:

1. Are the curves actually telling something that I'm not understanding or there's a programming error misleading me ?
2. If the curves are not wrong, what is actually happening with the changing of the first training size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I made a sight mistake.
When looking at the learning curves for `train_sizes_1` and `train_sizes_2` I thought the graphs were pretty much the same because the training and validation points were too close to each other and I uploaded the learning curves of `train_sizes_1`.
The problem is that:

1. `train_sizes_1` and `train_sizes_2` don't have the same number of sizes
2. `train_sizes_1` last size isn't the whole training set

So I made a k-cross validation with `train_sizes_2` and the right learning curves are   [image]

Now you can slightly see that the training error gets higher than the valiation error and than decreases until it overlaps with the validation error(like what happens with `train_sizes_3`).
As a matter of fact, the mean training and validation errors for `train_sizes_2` are

```
Mean training scores   
 1       -0.000000
9523     4.196595
25792    4.188449
43648    4.178641
61504    4.174143
79360    4.174099

--------------------

Mean validation scores
 1        12.748529
9523      4.174330
25792     4.174154
43648     4.174196
61504     4.174180
79360     4.174185
```

and for `train_sizes_3` are

```
Mean training scores
 79       4.163410
9523     4.196595
25792    4.188449
43648    4.178641
61504    4.174143
79360    4.174099

--------------------

Mean validation scores
 79       4.222444
9523     4.174330
25792    4.174154
43648    4.174196
61504    4.174180
79360    4.174185
```

When using 1 sample as a starting size the errors were too high and the next ones were too low so the matplotlib graph couldn't show the visual difference that well.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code. As shown in your article, with only one sample for the training, you'll have no difficulties to find a slope that intercept your sample. The training error is then O but the validation error is high (high bias & high variance).

[image]